# Performance of Union as a subquery vs Individual

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [event] (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    eventname1 nvarchar(50),
    eventname2 nvarchar(50),
    eventname3 nvarchar(50),
    eventname4 nvarchar(50),
    eventname5 nvarchar(50),
    eventname6 nvarchar(50),
    eventname7 nvarchar(50),
    eventname8 nvarchar(50),
    eventname9 nvarchar(50),
    eventname10 nvarchar(50),
    eventname11 nvarchar(50),
    eventname12 nvarchar(50)
);
```

Then I have data like this :

```
INSERT INTO [event] VALUES('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');
INSERT INTO [event] VALUES('2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2');
INSERT INTO [event] VALUES('3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3');
INSERT INTO [event] VALUES('4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4');
INSERT INTO [event] VALUES('5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5','5');
INSERT INTO [event] VALUES('6','6','6','6','6','6','6','6','6','6','6','6');
```

The question is which union SQL is better :

1)

```
SELECT eventname1,del_flag FROM [event]   WHERE del_flag = '0' AND eventname1 LIKE '%1%'
UNION
SELECT eventname2 AS eventname1,del_flag FROM [event] WHERE del_flag = '0' AND eventname1 LIKE '%1%'
.....
SELECT eventname12,del_flag FROM [event]   WHERE del_flag = '0' AND eventname12 LIKE '%1%'
```

2)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT eventname1,del_flag FROM [event]
    UNION
    SELECT eventname2 AS eventname1,del_flag FROM [event] 
    ....
    SELECT eventname12 AS eventname1,del_flag FROM [event] 
) as [event]
WHERE del_flag = '0' AND eventname1 LIKE '%1%'
```

I have see the execution plan and live query statics . But it's all same. So I don't know which is better. I have thinked about unpivot query but it seems slow perfomance. Can anyone explain me which is better for a large data.

EDIT 1 : 
I'm looking for output like this

```
eventname
1 (eventname1)
2 (eventname2)
3 (eventname3)
4 (eventname4)
5 (eventname5)
6 (eventname6)
```

and which has a better performance

Comment: A SQL compiler does its best to come up with an optimal execution plan, so it's no surprise that both execution plans are identical. There is always a limit to what a SQL compiler can do of course.

Comment: Define "better"

Comment: what is the output that you are looking for. Please add the output to the question.

Comment: I'd edit the Alias for the second query to match the name you wanted too though

Comment: I have edit question . I have add output and I want to define which has better performance

Comment: UNPIVOT should be better as that just needs a single pass through the table, not 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is marginally better, because the filtering happens before the `union`.  `union` removes duplicates, so that incurs overhead.

A better approach is to unpivot the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.eventname, e.del_flag
FROM event e CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (eventname1), (eventname2), . . .
     ) v(eventname)
WHERE e.del_flag = 0 AND e.eventname LIKE '%1%';
```

This is better because it only needs to read the table once, rather twelve times.  However, it is still incurring overhead to remove duplicates.

Comment: Since I can't get any more answer so I will approve this answer